# Parse JSON string in Airflow

Tags: json, airflow

I have written a Dag in airflow using SimpleHttpOperator. By default this operator decides the success or failure using status code. But in my case we also receive a response in form of JSON. I want to parse that response JSON and fetch a particular value from it to check its success or failure.

```
task1 = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='invoke',
        method='GET',
        endpoint='/xyz',
        http_conn_id='public_service_ip',
        log_response=True,
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        response_check= lambda response: True if response.json()['Success'] == "true" else False,
        xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

Sample Response JSON

```
{"Data":"{}","ErrorCode":null,"Success":true}

{"Data":null,"ErrorCode":"Invalid IP : x.x.x.x","Success":false}
```

I want to fetch the value of success. But when the dag is executed, the response_check attribute returns false in both the cases even if value of success is true or false.

Can anyone please help me with the same.

Comment: did you get the ans ?